# What is the meaning of word "standards"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In Caroyln's murder case, Mr Sabich(defendant) hired Stern to be his
lawyer and Stern asking about bribe question to Horgan(Victim's Witness). but Witness's 
lawyer objected to it and Stern saying this words to Judge:

> The witness has testified on direct examination  that Mr. Sabich did
>   not bring to his attention information that he regarded as pertinent.
>   The defense is entitled to explore Mr. Horgan's **standards** in this
>   regard.

This Bribe question may land Horgan in another case.

Comment: Not my downvotes, but you're receiving them most likely because you didn't consult a dictionary and explain why the definitions there did not clarify things for you. I answered because the phrase **explore his standards in that regard** might confuse a learner in that the verb **explore** might seem odd and the phrase "in that regard" did not have a crystal clear referent.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I never asked about **Downvotes**, May I ask why you post the comment about **Downvotes**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably ***standards*** in this regard would refer to the *criteria* Horgan uses to judge whether something is "pertinent".

P.S. "explore" in this context would mean  to ask questions about them, the better to understand them.